# XR Interaction Toolkit XR Grab Interactable with box collider causes continuous movement to stop working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a model with a simple box collider, a rigidbody, and an XR Grab Interactable component. For some reason when I pick up the model in game, no matter which direction I am trying to go I always go backwards, and at a way higher speed than I set. Does anyone know what could be causing this? Here is a video of me picking up the object and then spinning my joystick to move around: https://streamable.com/qlh2rl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because the collider on your rig is colliding with the grab object and thus causing the issues.

put the grab interactables and interactors on a different physics layer and your rig on other layer.

then from the physics tab in project settings turn the physics between both the layers off and you'll be good to go.